# Angular fire latest version functions does not recognize app

Tags: angular, firebase, dependency-injection, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm setting up my Angular / Firebase project with AngularFire. I got the realtimedatabase and auth working, yet my functions do not seem to work. I provide them the exact same way as my database and auth.

providing in app.module.ts looks like:

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfig)),
provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
provideDatabase(() => getDatabase()),
provideFunctions(() => getFunctions()),
```

These are imported from:

```
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideDatabase, getDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
```

and used like this, DB example:

```
 import { Database } from '@angular/fire/database';
 private database = inject(Database);
```

Same for Functions which seems to be breaking:

```
import { Functions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
functions = inject(Functions);
```

the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app).
```

Which tells me that functions isn't properly being provided? Even though i do it exactly the same for auth and database providers..

Any thoughts?